# I need to minus some value from a fixed number in jsf

Tags: el, jsf-1.2

I need to minus some value (value coming from DB though Databean and VO) here is my code:

```
value="200 - #{pc_costReportDataBean.adjustCostVo.explanationLength}"
```

but the problem is result coming like [200-0].

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
value="#{200-pc_costReportDataBean.adjustCostVo.explanationLength}"
```

The `#{}` means that the whole expression inside will be evaluated. The values outside will be just treated as Strings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but after use this pics of code some error coming in jsp like "Attribute expects settable value, but expression is not settable"

Comment: After implemented this code in production error coming like "Conversion Error setting value '200' for 'null Converter'.
"

Comment: Maybe the field of the underlying bean which this value is mapped to is of type String instead of a numeric type like int?

Comment: No ,value returning int only i have checked in log it is coming perfectly but when comes to jsp it not taking any mathematical calculation.